# How to run Python3 function script in terminal Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

so far I have been ok with debugging and running in a python debug terminal. Now that I'm being forced into functions, i have to input the arguments when launching the script, for example:

`./python.py BIRTHDAY AHMED`

and have it spit out something along the lines of this:

`have a happy BIRTHDAY enjoy the day AHMED`

problem comes down to me not knowing how to setup a terminal for such use. i have a bash terminal, however it wont recognize my python interpreter (#!/usr/bin/python3).
I added `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"` to my user settings to gain the bash terminal as well as installed Git.

Any ideas on how i can get a work in terminal that i can input arguments and recieve an output would be most appreciated. (running on windows 10)

Comment: The integrated terminal works just like the one separate from VS Code. Please clarify exactly what isn't working.

Comment: the basht erminal does not recognize both my interpreter, nor does it recognize any other file besides a .sh

Comment: That is correct. Unless you have WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) installed, normal bash commands won't work on Git Bash, which is what you are attempting to use as a terminal in VS Code.

Comment: so should i install the linux subsystem for windows as i have windows 10?

Comment: If you have Windows 10, either install WSL or if not, add python to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing the path of Git Bash, which only provides enough bash-like functionality to use git. That is why running `.sh` (Bash Scripts) or `.py` files doesn't work by default.

If you add python to your PATH environment variable, that will make it so running `python.exe filename.py [ARGS]` will work on the Integrated Terminal.

Another solution is to [install WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) if you are on Windows 10, which does provide full* bash functionality under a modified Ubuntu shell. Then just provide VSCode the path to the WSL `bash.exe`. ([How to here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows))

Comment: installed WSL and pointed to bash. forgot to enable developer mode, ran into a lot of trouble there with it off

Comment: Is your computer fine? As far as I know, it won't install if developer mode  isn't on.